# horizontal tree with graphviz_layout

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx, pygraphviz

in python, with networkx. I can plot a vertical tree with :

```
   g=nx.balanced_tree(2,4)
   pos = nx.graphviz_layout(g, prog='dot')
   nx.draw(g,pos,labels=b_all, node_size=500)
   plt.show()
```

similar to

```
   [root]
     |
  |      |
 node   node
```

how I can plot a horizontal tree ?

```
        -- node
[root] - 
        -- node
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pass `-Grankdir=LR` option to dot:

```
pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot', args="-Grankdir=LR")
```

https://graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html

https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rankdir